# How to remove a key/value pair from yaml dump, in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, yaml

Suppose I have a naive class definition:

```
import yaml
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.abc = 1
        self.hidden = 100
        self.xyz = 2

    def __repr__(self):
        return yaml.dump(self)

A()
```

printing

```
!!python/object:__main__.A
abc: 1
hidden: 100
xyz: 2
```

Is there a clean way to remove a line containing `hidden: 100` from yaml dump's printed output? The key name `hidden` is known in advance, but its *numeric* value may change.

Desired output:

```
!!python/object:__main__.A
abc: 1
xyz: 2
```

FYI: This dump is for display only and will not be loaded.

I suppose one can suppress key/value pair with key=`hidden` with use of `yaml.representative`. Another way is find `hidden: [number]` with RegEx in a string output.

Comment: Does `hidden` *need* to be an attribute of the class? Could it be a global within the class?

Comment: @erip: What do you mean by global within a class? `self.hidden` is at class-scope too :)

Comment: Instead of being a member of`self` (i.e., `self.hidden = "foo"`), make it a class global with just `hidden = "foo"`. This might not be a good idea depending on the application, but it's a suggestion.

Comment: `re.sub('hidden: \d+\n', '', s)`, `'\n'.join([l for l in s.splitlines() if not l.startswith('hidden:')])`, but I wouldn't do that, I would look for a way to change behavior of `yaml.dump` instead.

Comment: @erip: thanks for clarifying. In this case, I'm using members of `self`. I had some other (unresolved) dumping issues with class globals.

Comment: @GingerP++: I agree :)

Comment: @Emily: `json` have much better docs than `pyyaml`, I'd use it instead while `pyyaml`'s docs are hard to fully understand. As a bonus, YAML is (almost) superset of JSON, so you should be able to switch to YAML without converting the data.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. I'll check out `json` too.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong tool for the job. YAML is for encoding data (mostly to/from files). `__repr__` is for displaying the object.

Comment: I tried many tools (`vars`, `pprint`, ...) to pretty print my (rather complex hierarchical) objects, but `yaml` seems to do what I need in a couple of lines. What other tool would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the documentation for pyyaml and did not find a way to achieve your objective. A work-around would be to delete the attribte `hidden`, call `yaml.dump`, then add it back in:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        hidden = self.hidden
        del self.hidden

        return yaml.dump(self)

        self.hidden = hidden
```

Taking a step back, why do you want to use `yaml` for `__repr__`? Can you just roll your own instead of relying on `yaml`?

Answer (score 1):

`json` is mature solution and (at the moment of writing) have much better docs than `pyyaml`;
I'd use it instead while `pyyaml`'s docs are hard to fully understand. As a bonus, YAML is (almost) superset of JSON, so you'll be able to read your data as YAML without converting it.
<sup>However, to easily use all goodies of YAML you will probably have to convert the data to YAML</sup>

`json` module is unable to serialize custom objects by default, but it can be easily extended:

```
import json

def default(o):
    if isinstance(o, A):
        result = vars(o).copy()
        del result['hidden']
        result['__class__'] = o.__class__.__name__
        return result
    else:
        return o

json.dumps(A(), default=default) # => '{"__class__": "A", "xyz": 2, "abc": 1}'
```

If you don't want to write `default=default` everywhere you `dumps`, you can create custom serializer:

```
dumper = json.JSONEncoder(default=default)
dumper.encode(A()) # => '{"__class__": "A", "xyz": 2, "abc": 1}'
```

Or, to be able to easily extend it even further via subclassing:

```
class Dumper(json.JSONEncoder):
    __slots__ = ()
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, A):
            result = vars(o).copy()
            del result['hidden']
            result['__class__'] = o.__class__.__name__
            return result
        else:
            return super().default(o)

dumper = Dumper()
dumper.encode(A()) # => '{"__class__": "A", "xyz": 2, "abc": 1}'
```

Note that fields in JSON are unordered.
Also, if you want to use this, I'd advise you not to serialize dict with key `__class__`, because it might be hard to distinguish it from serialized object.

[See it working online](https://repl.it/B4gg/0)

Comment: Thanks. I still feel that `json` yields to `yaml`, which (by default) omits quotation marks (on key names) in print out. My objects have lots of key-value pairs. The goal is to dump a pretty-structure on screen for further analysis. I want to suppress some housekeeping key/value pairs. I can do most of this successfully with just a few lines. Just need to hide those housekeepers in a line or two :)